# Access Samba share with different credentials in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, samba

Windows 7 64-bit. Logged in to the windows machine with cached networks credentials.

I'm trying to access a samba share on the current network. The Windows machine is logged in to "itself" with cached credentials from a different network domain.

When I try accessing \server\share on my current network, I immediately get the message that I don't have permissions to access the share. I get no login prompt, so I'm guessing that windows insist on using the credentials I'm logged in with to access the share, which naturally won't work.

I even managed to "add a new network credential" somewhere, where I added the server and share, and the correct username and password. Didn't help, not even after rebooting the machine. And now I cannot for the life of it find where I did it.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: I posted it in SO by mistake, I'm afraid, thinking I was posting it in here.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Just wanted to confirm you were a real person.

Comment: Are you the admin for the Samba share? If so, have you added the user to the /etc/samba/smbpasswd file?

Comment: Yup. I'm accessing the samba share from another linux machine, as well as from a mac.

Answer (score 1):

"I don't have permissions to access the share" usually means the credentials *did* work, but that particular account is, well, not permitted to access the share...

To specify different credentials, try:

```
net use \\server Username * /savecred
```

Comment: Well, to be precise (using equivalent examples): The windows computer logs on to a domain, using the credentials user/pass. When not connected to the domain network, I log in with the same cached credentials. When I come home, I connect to a wlan and no domain/workgroup. The server in question is a linux server running samba, and the samba share has the following user credentials: bruker/passord. When I try to access the share, I get the above mentioned error. Of course the credentials don't work - they're no the right ones. The problem is, however, that I have no option to actually specify

Comment: credentials - windows just assumes them, and never asks. I'll try accessing it with net use, however. Thanks for the tip.